# How to display two linear axis in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have one LineSeries and one BarSeries, and I need two use two Y-axis. How I can achieve this in Nativescript angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple axes via HTML as follows:

```
<RadCartesianChart tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Left"></LinearAxis>
    <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis verticalLocation="Down"></CategoricalAxis>

    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="RateA" [items]="rateA" stackMode="Stack" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount"></LineSeries>
    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="RateB" [items]="rateB" stackMode="Stack" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount"></LineSeries>
    <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="RateC" [items]="rateC" stackMode="Stack" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount"></LineSeries>
    <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries seriesName="Total" [items]="total" stackMode="Stack" categoryProperty="Country" valueProperty="Amount">
        <LinearAxis tkBarVerticalAxis horizontalLocation="Right"></LinearAxis>
    </BarSeries>
</RadCartesianChart>
```

The full example can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/chart/axes/multiple/chart-axes-multiple.component.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks! But I didn't find any example with two LineSeries on different axis. Do you know is this possible too?